# How can I change the language of a posted view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contacts, mail-form

I have a view that is called using the method post and not get. But when I want to change the language of the view in `rails` using `I18n` and `change_locale_path(:es)`. I have routing problems because there is no route that `matches [Get]"/Contacts"` and `localhost:3000/contacts` is called with `post`.

My apllication.html.erb is:

```
<li><%= link_to (t ('layouts.language1')) , change_locale_path(:es) %></li>
```

My routes file is:

```
resources :contacts, only: [:new,:create]
get 'gmm/home' 
get 'gmm/about'
get 'gmm/services'
get 'gmm/contact'
get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
```

I also tries adding this to the routes file.

```
match ':controller/:action' ,via: [:get,:post]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add `method: :post` to send request as post.

```
<li><%= link_to (t ('layouts.language1')) , change_locale_path(:es), method: :post %></li>
```

Secondly: if you are on `/contacts` page and want to change locale. You can send change locale request using ajax also.

For sending request using ajax:

```
<li><%= link_to (t ('layouts.language1')) , change_locale_path(:es), method: :post, remote: true %></li>
```